Tableau Dual Axis Report Joined Data
I have 2 sets of data one has the locations of stores and their average sales by month of products. The other has the combined average sales by month of all the stores. I have a dual axis graph so I can make the average line extra thick and have different values when you float over it. The problem I am having is, when I filter to any given store, the average for any product that store never sold vanishes. That is to say, I want the entire average line to always show, I want it to filter by Date range, but not product so that I can see if I look at Store A, they had 0 sales of Product X,Y,Z but the averages were 20,30,40 at the other stores. Is it as simple as switching the join? I mean join the stores to the averages. I know in SQL it would be a LEFT join from the averages to the stores.

" I want the entire average line to always show"  -- look into LoD.  It's hard to say exactly what you need to do, but a LoD will allow you to set the calc to a specific level, which might be FIXED to Date but it's hard to say without knowing your data set / viz structure. You'll also want to read up on how LoD works with order of operations / processing in Tableau so you know how it works with filters

The data is 2 separate queries joined together on their key items. Originally, I tried to blend them, but I found that is basically useless.  In regular SQL you would just LEFT JOIN the data and get NULL for all the stores that didn't have sales for which is exactly what I want, however, I do not want to do it before hand because I want to be able to keep the dual axis.

If your viz looks correct but behaves incorrectly on filter, then it's likely a LoD you'll need and not an issue with the JOIN. The LoD would allow that line to be excluded from your product filter (so it remains the unaffected by the filter) but be impacted by a date filter.

Thanks, for the help, from what I am reading it sounds like I would want to do a Exclude LoD and exclude the 2 filters that I do not want to affect my average.  Something like below. However, this still changes nothing. I also tried fixed, which definitely was wrong it just became a straight line.
{EXCLUDE [Location Name],[Location ID] : AVG([PERCENTAGE (Custom SQL Query1)])/100}

It weird that tableau works this way. Its a very simple thing in Excel or SQL. I have 2 data sets 1 has the numbers 1-100 and the other 1-50. when I combined them Tableau tells filters the data to only show me 1-50 even though there is data in the data set 51-100. I have tried Left Join/Right/Outer joins, relationships, LoDs nothing. As soon as I add the 1-50 data set it clear all the data for 51-100 even though it is clearly there. Even if I click Analysis and say "show empty columns it shows 51-100 empty meaning it knows exactly what I have, but it will not populate the data.

Tableau is nothing like Excel. And similar to SQL, but still very different from it. I think you'll need to edit your question and provide an MRE in order to get meaningful help.

I was not able to fix in Tableau, but what I did was I took both data sets and cross joined the filter column and the filled with Nulls where nothing was available. So now it works. Thanks for trying to help I know it's a pain / impossible when you cannot see the workbook.
